# How can I get the full Save As Dialog Box in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

How can I get the full Save As (Save Attachment) Dialog Box in Windows 7 instead of the limited one (Save As) that has common destinations such as Recent Places, Desktop, Libraries, Computer, and Network on the left side?

[image: Screenshot of Save As Dialog Box]

Comment: What is the context of this question? Are you writing an application? Are you in a specific program and using its "open" function? Please expand on your question. As your question is currently written we cannot be certain what you are actually asking and what sort of solution you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

To further answer what I mean.

The application open is Evernote and I am attempting to save an image file from one of the notes to the computer.

The dialog box in the screenshot is the ‘Save As’ screen. I’m looking for the more detailed dialog box that looks more like an Windows Explorer window (that has Favorites on the left panel, and a file path bar which would make navigation to a destination folder much easier.

Comment: Your comment below was posted as an answer. It is OK to answer your own question, but comments should be placed as comments under the answer or question they are intended to comment on. It's a bit different from a forum in here because we are very focused on questions and answers. Comments are kept out of the Q&A main spaces.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for the "Navigation Pane". The Navigation Pane contains the hierarchical folder view of your PC. In the screenshot you have shown, you still have access to the full range of locations where you can save your file, it's just a different view. If you click on "Computer" on the left, and then click "View > Details" you will get a similar view to the navigation Pane.

If you don't see the Navigation Pane anywhere, I would advise you try opening a new explorer window, selecting "Organize > Layout > Navigation Pane" and turning the Navigation Pane on and see if that fixes the issue. If it does not, the application is using a Windows XP style common File/Open dialog box, and it is not (without hacking your operating system) possible to change the dialogue box.

In other words, there are two kinds of "Save As" Dialogue boxes, the old style that doesn't have the navigation pane, and the new style, which can have the navigation pane. If the application uses the old style, you're out of luck in terms of viewing the hierarchical folder view, you'll have to use the Icon, List, or Details view. I hope that helps.

Comment: Basically, it's up to the application developer to determine what they need and what is appropriate for their use. If you're the dev, you can choose what to use. If you're just the user, there is no way to specify the dialog you'll see.